# How to set the database schema for the Quartz scheduler with Spring Boot and Flyway?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, database-schema, flyway

I have a Spring Boot application that uses the Quartz scheduler with a PostGreSQL databse as storage. I'm migrating it from running with it's own db with the `public` schema to running against a shared db with one schema per application. The schema is managed with [flyway](/questions/tagged/flyway).

During testing (with [testcontainers](/questions/tagged/testcontainers)) startup of the application fails with

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "qrtz_locks" does not exist
  Position: 15
```

although flyway has previously created that table in the schema `app_test_hub_scheduler_v0`.

Config is

```
spring:
  jpa.properties:
    hibernate.default_schema: app_test_hub_scheduler_v0
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    schemas: app_test_hub_scheduler_v0
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_schema: app_test_hub_scheduler_v0
  quartz:
    jdbc:
      schema: app_test_hub_scheduler_v0
jdbcUrlParams: ?currentSchema=app_test_hub_scheduler_v0
```

The quartz properties are

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=test-hub-scheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=50
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=qrtz_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=false
```

It seems quartz doesn't get the schema name. How do I set it?

Comment: can you check and confirm whether LOCK table exists in your schema.I assume since you are managing quartz tables via flyway ,the table might be missing the prefix which you declare in the quartz.properties  tablePrefix=qrtz_

Comment: @user06062019 Flyway: `Executing SQL: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS qrtz_locks`

Comment: can you try setting the schema_name in table prefix and give it a try

Comment: @user06062019 Yes, that works: `org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=app_test_hub_scheduler_v0.qrtz_`. Please make that an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quartz scheduler can take the schema_name in account if the following property is declared in the quartz.properties.For example

```
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=app_test_hub_scheduler_v0.qrtz_
```

Here

```
app_test_hub_scheduler_v0 = is schema name and
qrtz_= is quartz table prefix
```